# Maven runs all test in class despite specifying single test

Tags: maven, junit

I'm trying to run a single test within a test class but all the tests within the class get run.

I'm running it like so

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod
```

and I've tried

```
mvn clean test -Dtest="TestClass#testMethod"
```

and

```
mvn clean test "-Dtest=TestClass#testMethod"
```

but nothing seems to work. All the tests within TestClass get run...

What am I missing here?

Path to test: /development/src/test/java/com/company/project/TestClass.java

TestClass.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {

  @Test
  public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("running1");
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod2() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("running2");
  }
}
```

Output from `mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod1 clean test`

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ lazarus ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestClass
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

..

running1
running2
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.536 sec - in TestClass
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 50.452 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-01T13:42:51-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/1781M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit 2: Power mock dependency is causing the issue?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <classifier>full</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Well... do you have a `TestClass` class with a `testMethod` method? Can you show it, along with its full path on disk?

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: @Tunaki I'm using 4.12

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the `SpringRunner` which requires JUnit 4.12 anyway. This should work, I can't reproduce the behaviour with the exact same class you have... (testing with Spring Boot 1.5.1, and Spring 4.3.7)

Comment: @Tunaki apparently its the powermock dependency (added above) that is causing the issue? Ever seen that before?

Comment: Very nice! Yes, I can reproduce this now, and the issue is that TestNG is actually being used to run the tests, while your annotation are for JUnit! I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tricky bug. The `powermock-mockito-release-full` dependency brings on the classpath TestNG, and you want to be running your test with JUnit, since your test methods are annotated with JUnit `org.junit.Test` annotation. This is the cause of the malfunction.

When you don't specify which provider to use to run the tests, [the Surefire Plugin will try to be clever](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html) and detect it for you. The purpose is that if you depend on TestNG, it will automatically select its TestNG provider to run your tests. Conversely, if you depend on JUnit, it will use its JUnit provider. This even [depends on the version of TestNG or JUnit](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/tree/surefire-2.19.1/surefire-providers). This is extremely useful to simplify configuration, but when both are on the classpath... it is unspecified what will happen. It turns out that Surefire 2.19.1 will select TestNG first (cf. the source code [auto-detecting the provider](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L2681-L2692), and [TestNG being specified before any JUnit specific providers in the list of well known providers](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L906-L910)). You can check that this is the case looking at the logs in debug mode (with `-X`); when starting the tests, you'll see

```
Running com.company.project.TestClass
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG60Configurator
```

demonstrating that the TestNG provider is being used.

There would be a couple of solutions here. First, having both TestNG and JUnit on the test classpath is probably not something you want anyway, unless you explicitly want to use both frameworks for your tests. As such, the minimalist solution would be to exclude TestNG entirely as a transitive dependency of `powermock-mockito-release-full`, so that it doesn't end up in the test classpath, and indeed, adding

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

solves the issue, and only 1 test is run with the right `-Dtest=TestClass#testMethod1` invocation.

Perhaps a better second solution is to remove the dependency on `powermock-mockito-release-full` which brings *a lot* of other things on the test classpath that you most likely don't want. Notably, it even bring sources JAR! If you only depend on `powermock-module-junit4` instead, the issue is also resolved, without cluttering your classpath. You can add a dependency on Mockito, or other specific components that you need, yourself.

A third solution would be [to force the use of the JUnit 47 provider](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html). This will make sure the tests are run with JUnit and not TestNG, even if both are in the test classpath.

Comment: Woah...thanks for the awesome answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right. Just move the `test` to the end of the line.

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod clean test
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple. That didn't work either. It's a spring boot app and I'm using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest annotations. Does that make a difference?